# How can I apply a .toggle query ONLY to the child element of div.selected?

Tags: jquery, show-hide, chap-links-library, vis.js

I am using [vis.js](http://visjs.org/) with [custom styles](http://kathep.com/tests/07_research_timeline/css/styles.css) and jquery behaviors.

I want to write a jquery statement that says:

> Every time `.item.range` or `.item.box` is selected, show
>   `p.extra` within the selected item. Every time anything else on the
>   page is clicked, hide `p.extra` in the previously selected item.

Every time `.item.range` or `.item.box` is selected, they are appended with the style `.selected`, so I had hoped I could use this to define a parent. But I have been trying for several hours to get this to work without luck. So far I have tried to do this using `.toggle`, `.toggleclass`(then applying the behaviors to the new class in css), and `.show/hide`.

I am limited in terms of naming within the confines of vis.js. For example, I can't assign a custom class only to the p tags I want to show hide - each class I assign is shared with 30 other .item elements I don't want to move. This is why I want the script to recognize which parent element the p.extra tag is in.

In my efforts I have written wrong scripts such as:

```
$( 'p' ).toggle( "slow" ) //makes all p tags on the page toggle about 11 times before stopping.
$( '.extra' ).toggle( "slow" ) //makes all p.extra tags on the page toggle.
$( '.selected','.extra' ).toggle( "slow" ) //makes selected element hide and all .extra elements on the whole page toggle.
```

The problem i have run into when searching for an answer is that all the examples I could find only relate to unnested elements (I would post links to what I have tried, but since it is my first post SO won't let me!).

Here is a snippet of the relevant HTML generated when using the vis.js timeline:

```
<div class="item range output" style="left: 806.26204476358px; width: 333.050742629105px; top: 75px;"><div class="content" style="left: 0px;">
    <h3> NEH Digital Humanities </h3>
    <p class="extra"> Communication + Place. Finish draft of journal article </p>
    <div class="type"> output </div>    
  </div></div>
  <div class="item range in_process selected" style="left: 437.527293995642px; width: 344.945412008717px; top: 75px;"><div class="content" style="left: 0px;">
    <h3> NEH Digital Humanities </h3>
    <p class="extra"> Guide to Winning. Work with student editor for 30 hours to finish some more 300 online videos. </p>
    <div class="type"> in_process </div>
```

And here is a snippet of the javascript in my file:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 // create a handlebars template
 var source = document.getElementById('template-main').innerHTML;
 var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

 // load data via an ajax request. When the data is in, load the timeline
  $.ajax({
  url: 'data/basic.json',
  success: function (data) {
      // hide the "loading..." message
      document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'none';

      // DOM element where the Timeline will be attached
      var container = document.getElementById('visualization');

      *snip!*

  // Create a Timeline
  var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, items, groups, options);
  document.getElementById('window1').onclick = function () {
        timeline.setWindow('2015-05-18', '2016-05-17');
    };
    document.getElementById('window2').onclick = function () {
        timeline.setWindow('2016-05-18', '2017-05-16');
    };
    document.getElementById('window3').onclick = function () {
        timeline.setWindow('2017-05-18', '2018-05-16');
    };
    document.getElementById('window4').onclick = function () {
        timeline.setWindow('2018-05-18', '2019-05-16');
    };
    document.onclick = function() {
        var selection = timeline.getSelection();
        timeline.focus(selection);
        //** I think the script using show-hide or toggle needs to go here **//
    };

 *snip!*    

</script>
```

I hope what I am asking makes sense to one of you, and that there is a relatively easy fix.

Can you help write the code I am looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3yc49pc3/).

hide all extra on page load

```
$('.extra').hide();
```

bind click event to item and range

```
$('.item,.range').click(function(){
    $('.extra').hide();
    $(this).find('.extra').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Yes! That is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you! I'll try it in my project later today.